# Считается ли плохим тоном убрать break из switch, если присутствует return?

Tags: javascript, php, switch, чистый-код

Можно ли отсюда убрать break? Или это будет "не по канону"?

```
    case "addition":
        return $a + $b;
        break;
    case "subtraction":
        return $a - $b;
        break;
    case "multiplication":
        return $a * $b;
        break;
```

Comment: после ретурна ничего работать не будет

Comment: так что дурной тон держать такое

Comment: Ответ не можно а нужно убрать

Comment: @AzizUmarov понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы опустил `switch` и предложил более компактную версию калькулятора

```js
const expressions = {
    '+': (a, b) => (a + b),
    '-': (a, b) => (a - b),
    '*': (a, b) => (a * b),
    '/': (a, b) => (a / b),
    '^': (a, b) => (Math.pow(a, b))
};

function calculator(a, b, expression) {
    if (!expressions.hasOwnProperty(expression))
        throw new Error(`Invalid expression - '${expression}'`);
    return expressions[expression](a, b);
}

console.log(3, '+', 2, '=', calculator(3, 2, '+'));
console.log(3, '-', 2, '=', calculator(3, 2, '-'));
console.log(3, '*', 2, '=', calculator(3, 2, '*'));
console.log(3, '/', 2, '=', calculator(3, 2, '/'));
console.log(3, '^', 2, '=', calculator(3, 2, '^'));
```